# Java: Tool to determine the dependents of every java class in a maven module

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, dependencies

I wonder if its a trivial question, which i am not aware.

In a multi-module maven project, lets say that there is a 'common' module. For example, there are 5 modules out of which 1 module is common. Is there a way to determine if the other 4 modules depend the common module class-wise i.e for each and every class in the common module, i want to know the classes in the other modules which depend on that class in common? (actually maven does not matter here though).
Does eclipse itself has this feature?

It would be great if the tool gives a diagramatic representation.

Comment: Class.forName("....") is not good here.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Maven doesn't work 'class-wise', module is its atomic element in terms of dependencies.

You can use `mvn dependency:tree` in order to get the dependencies per module, in eclipse/intellij enterprise edition you 
have a graphical representation for the results but that's it.

Basically you must differ between compile time and run time dependencies.

Of course if you have an 'unsatisfied' compile time dependency in some class, for example, using Logger but not having log4j/other relevant library in the class path you'll get the error *during the compilation of your class*, Its compiler's job, not maven's.

Now runtime dependencies are even harder to track, example:
if you're running inside of some container and you define your log4j library dependency in a 'provided' scope, then you're relying on container that it will bring that library to you and will take care of all the class loading stuff.
But How maven can know what's going on inside a container?

So, Bottom line, what's you're asking for is impossible in maven and I've tried to explain why :)

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse you can simply do that by selecting the class you want to examine and press CTRL-SHIFT-G which will you search for a reference within the workspace. In this case it means you have to have opened all the modules of the multi-module. The drawback is that you need to do this for every class you would like to know of.

Comment: Yes i am aware of the reference search but the idea is to indentify the classes which should not reside in the common module i.e. there can be a class, which is used by only one another module and its really not a common class. So that class should be moved out of the common module to the specific module. So here class is not the input but rather they are outputs. Just like how the maven dependency tree is shown at the artificat\module\jar level, i need the tree at the class level.

Answer (score 0):

I'm one of the developers, so I'm not unbiased, but I believe that [Restructure101](http://structure101.com/products/index.php#/refactor) is perfect for what you want. Point RS101 at the root POM and you'll see a dependency map of all the POMs, something like this:

[image]
Then you can chase dependencies from one pom to another by double-clicking to expand any item to whatever level you want. In this case I have drilled into Maven-core to discover what is used by code in maven-compat:

[image]

You can also use Restructure101 to reorganize classes between poms (like creation/improvement of a common pom as you mention), for example by dragging classes to new poms and seeing the effect on the pom-level dependencies. An action list is exported to your IDE.

The companion product Structure101 has related capabilities, worth checking, but I'd prefer Restructure101 for what you describe.